# How to create load more button without a plugin?

Tags: plugins, pagination, ajax

I'm using Jobroller Apptheme, it will show the first 10 jobs list in the home page with pagination which allows to go next page.

But I would like to create a load more button instead of normal pagination. So that, when we click on the load more button, it should display the next 10 jobs list below the previous list.

Is there any way to do this without a plugin?

Comment: If we were to show you how to do it without a plugin, we would have to write a brand new one. Every piece of code that enhances WP functionality is essentially a *plugin*. Doing it without you showing what efforts you took to achieve it falls into a "work for me for free" type of Question. Here's a [search query starting point](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22load+more%22+ajax).

Answer (score -3):

Without plugin?

Write a code right now or the easiest way go to http://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/ , download and copy paste the code in your theme.

Like brasofilo said. Every PHP function that enhances WP functionality is a plugin.

Comment: A link only is considered to be pure quality. Please at least share a bit of the needed code in the answer. If the link in the answer goes away, the answer will be worth less and the network suffers from link rot.